# Loopback4 calling HTTPS/REST service with self signed certificate

Tags: loopback4

How do I call https/rest endpoint with self signed certificate in Loopback4 with OpenApi connector? Is there any option to allow such certificate?

When I try to call the service.operation(), I get following exception:

```
Unhandled error in GET /user/8f9d1e34-c340-4ebe-af11-fa0c4575f676: 500 FetchError: request to https://localhost:8243/scim2/1.0.0/Users/8f9d1e34-c340-4ebe-af11-fa0c4575f676 failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\DEV_BTC\GIT\Foton\PIX\application\composite-services\perfil-usuario-ms\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Documentation for [REST Connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/REST-connector.html) mentions a parameter called `"strictSSL": false` to allow self-signed SSL certificates. Is there something similar to OpenAPI connector?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After opening a bug report that turned into question and then a feature request, Loopback's team created a new version of `loopback-connector-openapi` [to handle this option](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6527#issuecomment-706607031).

Basically you need to add this option to your datasource `config`:

```
const config = {
  (...)
  httpClientOptions: {
    agent: new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false}),
  }
  (...)
}
```